# How to escape @ symbol in XML tag

Tags: xml, web-services, escaping

I am using an XML request to generate the schema for my web service's request. A tag in the request is `<@type>` which is causing errors like

> Unable to generate the XSD document using the provided XML input. The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

I have tried hexadecimal representation of the symbol, but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@` character is **not permitted** in XML names by the [W3C XML BNF for component names](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar):

> ```
> NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] |
>                   [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] |
>                   [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] |
>                   [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] |
>                   [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
> NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] |
>                   [#x203F-#x2040]
> Name          ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
> ```

There is no escaping mechanism by which `@` could be added to an XML element name.  You'll have to use another character or characters if you want your XML to be well-formed (and therefore readable by standard XML libraries such as parsers).